# Writing to Memory-Mapped device in C++ on Ubuntu

Tags: c++

I have some doubts on writing to memory-mapped device on Ubuntu 20.04 on x64 machine using C++. Just seeking confirmation and pointers

My device in question is an PCI-DIO card. The address to each port is as follows:

```
    Type                    OFFSET                  Size
    IO_PORT(N)_DATA         0x40 + 0xN0             8 bit
```

The LSB bit is the data0 and MSB being the data7

When I use the command lspci -vvv, it gives me the detail

```
    ...............
    NUMA node:0
    Region 0: Memory at 92202000 (32bit non-prefetchable) [size=4k]
    Region 1: Memory at 92200000 (32bit non-prefetchable) [size=8k]
    ...............
```

I presume the BAR (base address register) is found at 92202000 or Region 0.

My code will be

```
// my simple code to write 1 to lower half and 0 to upper half of port 0
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

   volatile unsigned int& DIO_CARD = *((volatile unsigned int*)0x92202000);
   volatile unsigned int& DIO_PORT0 = *(&DIO_CARD + 0x40 + 0x00);

   DIO_PORT0 &= 0x0F;

   return 0;
}
```

The doubt i have:

1. Should the BAR be at region 1? How do one differentiate which memory region  to be used. Some other Memory-mapped device I seen have up to 4 memory region?
2. Another doubt I have is that I am supposed to have a 64 bit machine. So why is base address is only 32 bit?

Regards

Comment: All processes on Linux run in a virtual address space. Only the kernel actually has access to actual, raw, memory addresses. `root` czn open a /dev device to access kernel memory.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: So I have to run the program with administrator rights or the program has to be in kernel space and could not work in user space?

Comment: The only program in kernel space that runs is called "kernel". That's why it's called "kernel space". Your program has to be `root`, then open `/dev/mem`.